# Is electric current always necessary to make cathodic protection possible?

Tags: electrochemistry

Can a cathodic protection system still work if there is no current between the anode and cathode?

Comment: Yes I think it can be done but problem is that the process would become slow and  less effective so we need a current also to overcome driving forces.

Comment: By definition, cathodic protection relies on the electric current to prevent (or redeposit) the protected metal. For example, galvanized iron is protected by the dissolution of zinc and the current that generates.

Comment: To clarify the question: some cathodic protection systems work by impressing a specific (small) current using a power source connected to an inert electrode. Other cathodic systems use a sacrificial anode which (in theory) need not dissolve and produce a current, but just develops a protective voltage that prevents corrosion at the protected metal. Of course, the protected metal always corrodes a bit, and so the sacrificial anode corrodes a bit to prevent major corrosion.